# Facing NoClassDefFoundError error at Kafka-Spark Structured Streaming integration via PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using

- Spark version: **3.0.0-preview2**
- Scala version: **2.12**
- JAVA version: **1.8**
- Kafka Broker version: **2.2.0**

I have configured two JARS(**spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar** and **kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar**) at spark-defaults.conf file and saved the JARS in $SPARK_HOME/jars folder as well. when I tried to view the **Key,Value** of the data from Kafka servers(since the data from Kafka comes in K-V pairs in JSON format), I was facing the below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:580)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan.toMicroBatchStream(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$3(MicroBatchExecution.scala:102)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$tran29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:376)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$tran29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(S
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
        ... 30 more
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = 504665ad-c59a-4a85-8c46-4d6c741b0adf, runId = 36bc5028-6b34-4d6c-a265-4c38ce66cfcbError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:580)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan.toMicroBatchStream(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$3(MicroBatchExecution.scala:102)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$tran29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:376)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$tran29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(S
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
        ... 30 more
```

And here is the code I tried to view the Key-Value pair of the Kafka data

```
from pyspark import *
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.utils import *
from pyspark.streaming import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "XX.XX.XX.XX:9092,XX.XX.XX.XX:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2,topic3") \
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
  .load()

table = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

query = table \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .option("truncate","false") \
        .format("console") \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

Could anyone help me on resolving this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

your need add this jars in the $SPARK_HOME/JARS

1. commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar
2. kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar
3. spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar
4. spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar

Answer (score 3):

This is how I can config to run PySpark (verison with scala 2.12 Spark 3.2.1) Structure Streaming with Kafka on jupyter lab

First,I download 5 jars files and I put them in the folder /jars under my current project folder (just for local run I think):

- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar
- kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar
- spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.2.1.jar
- commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar
- spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar

The value of config spark.jars look like this  "<path-to-jar/test1.jar>,<path-to-jar/test2.jar>"

This is the actual code:

spark_jars =  ("{},{},{},{},{}".format(os.getcwd() + "/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar",
os.getcwd() + "/jars/kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar",
os.getcwd() + "/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.2.1.jar",
os.getcwd() + "/jars/commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar",
os.getcwd() + "/jars/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar"))

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", spark_jars).appName("Structured_Redpanda_WordCount").getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem by adding **spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar** in the **$SPARK_HOME/JARS** folder and in *spark-defaults.conf* file as

> ```
> spark.driver.extraClassPath       $SPARK_HOME/jars/*.jar
>
> spark.executor.extraClassPath     $SPARK_HOME/jars/*.jar
> ```

And ran the spark-submit command as below:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --jars $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview.jar,$SPARK_HOME/jars/kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar,$SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar test.py
```